# How to root micromax A116(canvas hd)

Tags: rooting, root-access, stock-android

Is there any way available to root this phone, stuck with this problem for so long.

Comment: See **Methods/Apps** here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device

Answer (score 0):

You can root it easily by using the Framaroot application.
Here is a link to the XDA thread, where you can find more information on the app. 
[XDA Thread Link for Framaroot app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276)